# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Bluetooth not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lts

I updated from Ubuntu 12.04 lts to 14.04 lts. Now, I can send files to my phone from PC but the reverse is not possible. There's a small lock sign subscripting the bluetooth icon in menu bar.

Does this lock signifies anything? Is it the reason I can't send files from my phone to PC? How can I send files from phone to PC?
Dear Ubuntu Lords, help.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: upload the screenshot to imgur.com and provide the link here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does this lock signifies anythting?

Yes if the lock is placed over blutooth icon, it means your bluetooth device is currently doing some operations.Lock will be automatically released when the corresponding operations are finished.

> How can I send files from phone to PC?

To send files from your phone to pc,

- Open **personal file sharing**  from dash.
- Enable *Receive files in Downloads folder over Blutooth* option at the bottom.And also enable *Notify about received files* option(To get notification upon received files via bluetooth).

  [image]
- Now send a file from your phone to PC.It will receive and then save the file inside `~/Downloads` folder.

Comment: The lock also indicates an established connection to a paired device.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3FkpiCs.png I installed Samba, but still am getting inactive "Share files over the Network". Is this related to topic?
Rest options are marked as shown.

Comment: @Potato_head: you don't need Samba for sharing files via Bluetooth.

Comment: @Potato_head Yes, i just tried that without installing samba.It works for me.